# Best way to decide between INSERT/UPDATE when unique ID is not available

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

Normally, when you are updating/inserting you use the `on duplicate key update` statement. But I'm inserting/updating such table:

```
id | neutral text | language | translation
---+--------------+----------+------------
 0 |       SUBMIT |       en |      Submit
 1 |       SUBMIT |       cs |     Odeslat
 2 |       SUBMIT |       fr |    Démarrer
```

I know I should've made 3 tables, but the project is not that large, so I decided to make it rather simple.

So now, when I want to change or add translation,  do something like this:

```
/*
 $this->lang_class->table = the name of my table
 $offset = neutral text name
 $this->lang = language name
 $value = new translation
*/
$this->debug("Translate attempt!<br />");
//Try to update, insert will be performed if update returns 0 rows
$update = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `{$this->lang_class->table}` SET content='$value' WHERE lang='{$this->lang}' AND name='$offset'");
$update->execute();  //try to update
if($update->rowCount()==0) {  //If no update happened, insert
  $this->debug("Creating new translation entry.<br />");
  $this->execsql("INSERT INTO `{$this->lang_class->table}` (lang, name, content) VALUES ('{$this->lang}', '$offset', '$value')");
}
return $value;
```

The problem is, that sometimes it may happen, that the new translation matches the old. In such case, the UPDATE will return 0 rows and INSERT is performed.
So what approach should I use, if I want to stick to only one table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you anyway running 2 queries, you can change first one:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM translate_table WHERE lang='$lang' AND name='$name';
```

And, after that, If this query returns 0, you can use your insert:

```
$this->execsql("INSERT INTO `{$this->lang_class->table}` (lang, name, content) VALUES ('{$this->lang}', '$offset', '$value')");
```

else run your update query:

```
$this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `{$this->lang_class->table}` SET content='$value' WHERE lang='{$this->lang}' AND name='$offset'")->execute();
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't realise that I didn't increase performace but reduced code with my solution.
Is select count(*) faster than normal select?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it's a little faster, but, in your case (you said, that It's a small project) it should doesnt matter. Also, you can use `SELECT id FROM translate_table WHERE lang='$lang' AND name='$name' LIMIT 1;` - it's faster :) And, If you are rarelly add new translations to table, think about indexes for "name" and "lang" fields

Answer (score 1):

The correct option is to create a unique composite index (name, lang) on your table and upsert the new value with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This is exactly the very case why the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` even exists in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key set on `neutral_text` and `language` fields. Especially that you should anyway create that key and it should be unique.

Comment: @TomášZato why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Yes, string field can be unique (and two fields also can create one unique key).

Comment: @Renan well, to be honest, I just assumed that comparing strings is too slow for it to be possible.
Actually, I never used other than standart auto-incremented integer named ID.
Posibility of two fields being unique is totally new idea for me, thank you :)

Comment: @TomášZato You say that you went for a non-optimal design for your database because it is small, then you don't want to compare small strings because it's a slow operation... You really should rethink your priorities.